# How can reincarnation lead to a second personality?

Tags: biology, secret-society

The reality that we live in exists in the same dimensional space as another reality inhabited by demons. We cannot see them, and yet they are there watching us. Where we sleep, eat, work, where are children play, in the bathroom when we take a crap, etc. They inhabit every crevice of our world, separated by a thin barrier between realities that protect us from them.

These demons are born from strong human emotions. Hate, fear, anger, etc, these intense drives that we feel resonate with the other reality, compounding together to form these entities. Most of these demons evaporate soon after they are formed. The strongest of these feelings create the strongest demons, which continue to exist and feed off of human emotions that created them.

A cult devoted to an ancient entity, Dagon, has conducted a millenia-long plan to allow the demons into our reality. Through selective breeding program enacted over thousands of years, a child would be born of a virgin woman that would act as a vessel for the demonic god. This "mother of chaos" heads this sinister cult and has kept herself pure for this very purpose. This dark messiah would be born with Dagon's soul in the form of a human, and act as a Trojan horse who would eventually break the barrier separating realities.

However, there is a problem. This child has no memories of its demonic existence, and considers itself fully human. The cult, in an attempt to bring the demon forth, subjected the child to various kinds of trauma. After walking away from the cult, it sought to live a normal life. As time passed, Dagon began to emerge as a second personality in the subconscious. The story revolves around the human and demon personalities of this individual fighting and trying to supress each other for domination, with one wanting to fulfill it's destiny and the other trying to stay human.

When Christ was born, he had no problem remembering what he was or what his purpose is. In some stories, he even boasted about it. This case is different. How would reincarnation lead to the formation of two personalities? A good answer would give a biological reason as to why this second personality would come to the forefront after remaining supressed early in life.

Comment: A psychological answer: It has long been thought that [multiple personality disorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissociative_identity_disorder) is caused by childhood neglect and abuse. But in truth the disorder isn't caused by childhood abuse. Rather, all persons are reborn with multiple personalities, of which one is dominant. The other personalities are suppressed after rebirth and get slowly integrated into the adult personality. But childhood trauma disrupts the integrative processes and weakens the repression of the second personality, allowing it to gain consciousness and influence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would propose the idea of "**`Reincarnation` is a VERY complicated procedure**"!

It would take tremendous "costs" to do such a thing! Whether it's energy or other things.

In order for a powerful demon to reincarnate, it must sacrifice many things. Such as compress his/her power to the lowest level.

You could imagine the "gate" to reincarnate in very small, the demon have to "squeeze" himself/herself through the gate.

In doing so, the demon inevitably put himself/herself into some kind of hibernate-like docile state and let the "human part" take charge for the time being.

And as the time go by, the demon part feed of the "emotions" of the human part and get stronger every single day, finally get powerful enough to "awake". Therefore participate in the part of "fighting for full control of the body".

As for "why" reincarnation lead to "two" personalities, I would propose instead of two independent full "personalities", it's more like "memories" of the demon half himself/herself!

When the demon get stronger and start to awake, memories of his/her old self start to flush back in fragments. And the human half always thinks it's just memories of bad dreams! But the "bad dreams" eventually lead to the "mental disorder" of the human and developing the "second (demon) personality"!

It could even be some old cliche setups such as when the "human" is sleeping, the "demon" awake and do some not-so-nice things! And therefore make the "human" begin to doubt himself and lead to the development of split personalities!

Answer (score 7):

I can provide an analogy based on real world.

Take a sheet of paper, write on it with a pencil. You can read what you wrote.

Now take a rubber and cancel the pencil writing, and write something else, again with a pencil.

The latest writing will be more visible, but on a careful inspection the old writing can be seen. Depending on where you focus your attention, you will read the old or the new writing.

The sheet is the soul, the pencil writing is the personality, the rubber is the reincarnation.

Comment: That's a pretty good analogy!

Answer (score 4):

Dagon awoke when the child was born, realised he was in a body unable to move, speak, focus his eyes or even control his own bowel movements. Not exactly a dignified entry for a Great Old One.

So Dagon slept, awaiting a more salubrious moment to make his presence felt.

Immortals being immortal, have a slightly different attitude to time than our fleeting existence can understand and he slept a couple of decades longer than he'd intended. In that time the body developed its own personality and a bad smoking habit.

Seeking hypnotherapy to help him stop smoking, the treatment accidentally awoke the sleeping Dagon.

Answer (score 2):

Personality is based on your brain's layout and neural connections. If the brain breaks down, for example during alzheimers disease, then the personality changes with it. Unfortunately this would mean that a portion of the brain would now need to be dedicated to Dagon, which would limit your persona's capabilities. So instead you give them Disassosiative identity disorder (DID, formerly Multiple Personalities Disorder). https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissociative_identity_disorder

DID is controversial, but it seems accepted that childhood abuse, violence or being present during wars etc can often lead to DID. Many of the symptoms seem to nicely fit into a Cthulu old one style story. From the often aggressiveness of the second personality to the lack of childhood memories for that personality to its emergence later in life to compatimentalized memories for each personality.

It is not strange to think that the cult will do some horrible things either to the kid or in front of the kid in order to strengthen the demon and make him more dominant. When this fails the child might have an opportunity later in life to seek help for what he has felt and witnessed, and the DID might set in.

Answer (score 0):

Do you remember all things from when you were a child? most of it is volatile but nevertheless it makes an impact on the development of personality.

Ok with that you can come up with an event that made the child be separated from the cult, being a government investigation, a revolt within the cult, non believers that thought a child should not be subjected to the cult and so they got him out, etc, etc, etc

The point is the child grew up without knowing anything form the cult or the ideas it had, because of that when he started 'hearing' Damon in his head or was old enough to understand that there was something within him that was different, he sought therapy, that in turn gave him medicine to suppress Damon...

Until he has no access to his pills anymore... This again can be anything, he accidentally flushed them in the toilet and his doctor is out of town, he got his backpack containing his pills robed while on vacation, etc, etc. whatever fits best in your story. And this would give an opening to Damon to take over.

Answer (score 0):

Passing through the veil between worlds takes something from you. Those that peer behind the veil are forever changed. No one is quite sure why or what it is, but there is something different about someone. Small changes, like no enjoying their favorite food anymore, or suddenly liking Justin Bieber's 'Baby' track. 
The veil is a barrier, meant to prevent passing between the worlds. To break this fundamental part of reality, one must lose something which identifies them as an individual. For those few rare and talented humans, who pierce it, even though only with their minds, the price is an emotion, feeling or memories. Those who do it enough times become unrecognizable after a while, completely new people. For the demon lord passing through with his whole being, it removed so much more than a few emotions. 
At the same time, the process of being born resets the soul to a blank slate, ready to form into a new persons being. 
This great being did not foresee this, as he is the first one to fully cross over to this side, hence, he is born as a new being without any memory of who he was.
But we all have those moments. You know those unexplained feelings of what we call Deja Vu. An irrational fear of swimming, not knowing that in your last life you died from drowning. Or the previous one where a snake bit you. Those things stay with you, as scars on your soul, never fully healing. 
That is why, in his moments of anger, or desperation, you can sometimes see the Demon lord in the young boys eyes, just beneath the surface, waiting to burst forth and claim this world for his own.